# How to differentiate "anchor links" from regular Links in CSS

Tags: html, css

How to differentiate "anchor links" from regular Links in CSS?!

Is there anything like pseudo-elements or checks IF the Link is an Anchor Link?!

I need to style them, put them in different colors.

It is an existing and old website where I am updating several things, and those Anchor Links were put there 8 years ago and many, it is too late to put them around a special class name;

It is a general question, Anchor Links as Anchor Links, they can not be referenced ather way & they are mixed with Regular Links on a 5 000 pages...

As for code example

```css
a {}

a::Anchor {??? Can I or Can't I}
```

```html
<article>
<a name="Mark1">Anchor Link 1</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 1</a>

<a name="Mark2">Anchor Link 2</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 2</a>

<a name="Mark3">Anchor Link 3</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 3</a>

<a name="Mark4">Anchor Link 4</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 4</a>

<a name="Mark5">Anchor Link 5</a>

<a href="http://google.xyz"> Reg Link 5</a>

</article>
```

Comment: Hello, can you post some of the HTML or CSS you are working with as an example?

Comment: Inspect the code and look at parent tags that have selectors, then use parent, child element selectors -> `.container a`. Also, you have no code in your question, you show no effort at trying to solve this on your own, the community will vote to close this question if you do not add some code that shows effort at solving this on your own.

Comment: It's a general Question - I expect an answer - We can Reference Anchor Tags or No,  We Can't; that's it for this question. I have thousand of pages & circumstances to use this for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your css file:
`a[href^="#"] { ... }`
That works only, without writing the page's name in your a - Element.
YES:
`<a href="#footer">` 
NO:
`<a href="current_page_name.html#footer">`